# Netsuite suitelet + Pass data from Get to Post

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I want to create a suitelet that will do the following. 
In the GET I want to have a nlapiSearchRecord that will show a list of custom records under certain criteria and a checkbox next to each.
The user will check some of them and submit.

At that point I want to take those records that are checked and use them to create Sales Orders equal to the number of records chosen by the user and with the data that are contained within each one.

What have I done is to show the list with check boxes, info that I want and a submit button. But I am at no clue how to pass / check the selected data at the POST so I can create those records. Can someone give any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to look into creating an `nlobjList` to contain your results. `nlobjList` has an `addSubmitButton` method that will add a native submit button to the form. When clicked, this will automatically `POST` the contents of the List back to the Suitelet.

You will want to limit the number of records you display and allow for selection as Suitelets are limited to 1000 governance units, and creating a Sales Order will take up 30 units per creation. You will not be able to create thousands of Sales Orders with this design.

I have a YouTube playlist about 2.0 Suitelets here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk2lG-SfZ3k&index=1&list=PLG2tK6Va2WUD9X87AS0vK6EJGAJvHGfU_

Comment: I must use nlobjForm because I want the user to check some of the lines and also enter additional info. This is a mean to lets say mass approve the creation SO and also add info to those SO's manually from a screen.

Comment: Principle is the same; the Form still has a native Submit button that `POST`s the form data back to the Suitelet.

Comment: how do you add more parameters to the form without adding new form fields ?

Answer (score 1):

Add standard submit button and get value as below from post.

var getValue =  request.getParameter('custpage_chkbox');